# Android ListFragment individually change row background color

Tags: android, list, listview, background, android-fragments

I have a ListFragment where I want certain rows to be a certain color.  I basically followed this: [Creating a ListView and setting the background color of a view in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575573/creating-a-listview-and-setting-the-background-color-of-a-view-in-each-row)

However, getView is never called. Does anyone know why?

```
    public class TrackerFragment extends ListFragment
{   
    private String[] list;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle myBundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(myBundle);

        list = null;
        ListView lv = getListView();
        setListAdapter(null);
        setEmptyText("Touch a connection to view tracker information.");
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    public void updateList(String[] list)
    {
        this.list = list;
        setListAdapter(new ColoredArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_item,list));
    }
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" 
    android:id="@+id/line">
</TextView>
```

I am updating the list like this from my activity:

```
TrackerFragment tf = (TrackerFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.tracker1);
tf.updateList(result);
```

My ColoredArrayAdapter

```
public class ColoredArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{

    private String[] list;

    public ColoredArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            Object[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        list = new String[objects.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            list[i] = (String) objects[i];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.line = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.line);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].contains("OUT OF LOCK"))
        {
            System.out.println("OUT OF LOCK");
            holder.line.setText(list[i]);
            //holder.line.setTextColor(R.color.white);
            holder.line.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
        }
        else if(list[i].contains("IN LOCK"))
        {
            System.out.println("In LOCK");
            holder.line.setText(list[i]);
            //holder.line.setTextColor(R.color.white);
            holder.line.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
        }
        else
            holder.line.setText(list[i]);
    }

    return vi;
}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Edit: added list_item.xml, where line is found.
Edit2: added extended array adapter

Now my problem is that, every row is either all green or red, when I just want certain individual rows to be either red or green.  Also, none of the text is showing up.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what is causing the `NullReferenceException`? That may help determine the cause of the crash. 

And: Does it only happen on the `OUT OF LOCK` line or also on the `IN LOCK` line?

Comment: It happens on both .setBackgroundResource() lines

Comment: And is `holder` OR `holder.line` resolving to null?

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere.

This means that the `holder.line` is the root of the problem. Now, where that is coming from:
- Is this happening when they are being inflated? If so, post the code where `line` comes from.
- Is this happening when the `convertView` is being used?

Comment: I added the xml where line is found.  Yes this is happening when convertView is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `getView` implementation should be moved into a `ListAdapter` implementation instead of your `TrackerFragment` class.  Since you're using `ArrayAdapter`, you can subclass that and put the code in there.  `ArrayAdapter` already implements `getView`, but you'll override it to provide your specialized behavior.

The reason you're getting a NullPointerException is because you're calling `getView` and passing in the list view, which does not have a tag associated with it -- so `holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();` assigns `null` to `holder`.  That said, you shouldn't be calling `getView` directly. The system will call that for you whenever it needs to display a list item.  When the system calls the `getView` method, it initially passes in `null` to have the views created, and every call where `convertView` is not `null` is a view created by that method.

Comment: Thank you, I am seeing colored rows, except now, its coloring every row green or red, and not displaying and text. I updated my post

Comment: Instead of looping through the array, you should just use the passed-in position, i.e. only use list[position] and set the background and text based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same problem as the post you linked: the getView() method isn't nested inside the class.

Or your code doesn't show anything that would call it either.

Comment: What does getView method isn't nested inside the class mean? and how would I fix it?

Comment: Your code doesn't show anything that is calling the getView() method. It isn't being called because you haven't called it anywhere. 
Try putting it inside your activityCreated method.

Answer (score 0):

The more I look over this, the more I wonder about the basic premise you are using.  I think you're making it overly complicated.  I would do it like this:

```
public View getView(View convertView)
{
    View vi = convertView;
    TextView viText = null;

    if (vi == null)
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    viText = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.line);

    if (viText == null) return vi;
    String viString = viText.getText().toString();

    if (viString.contains("OUT OF LOCK"))
    {
        viText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
    }
    else if (viString.contains("IN LOCK"))
    {
        viText.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
    }

    return vi;
}
```

I don't think you are using the `holder` in the way you think... the loop you have in there will just loop through setting the background resource to whatever the last trigger to set the backgroundResource is, no matter what.

If I have missed the point in this, let me know.  But, my basic thought would be to remove as much complexity as you can until it works, and if you've had to remove something important, slowly add it back in.

Comment: Well, I have the loop to loop through the list that the fragment has to find the row that I want to have a background color.

Comment: But, as far as your code sample goes, there's no relationship between the `holder` and the `list`.  Can you explain the relationship better?